# SQL Azure does not support SSIS package , what are the options we have for moving a inpremise solution to SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, azure, ssis

We have DB solution in-premise where we have a SSIS which scrubs the data from the main DB and populates it to a ReportDB . The scrubbing of the data and migration is done by SSIS package . Now we are planning to move this to SQL Azure and we know that we do not have support for the SSIS . I am looking out for options which we can use .

Comment: this article may help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj901708.aspx

Answer (score 0):

### Option A

Change your connection strings from using an OLE DB provider to an ADO.NET and go from, potentially having used, Windows authentication to definitely using SQL Server authentication. Verify everything continues to work and/or mitigate issues *i.e.* Lookup components support OLE DB providers or Cache Connection Manager so you'd need to preload the CCM. Change the selector in an Execute SQL Task from OLE DB to ADO, etc.

All looks good in a local environment? Deploy database objects to the SQL Azure DB, change connection strings in SSIS and run packages (locally) as normal. All should be well and good.

### Option B

You'll still need to make all the changes from Option A, but this will allow you to move your on premises SSIS processing to "the cloud."

Spin up an Azure VM and install a version of SQL Server to match your SSIS packages. Deploy the packages to the server and schedule execution. Ensure there are firewall exceptions to the Azure SQL DB from the VM instance.

### Option C

Rewrite everything in something else and deploy as an Azure worker. Or comingle the Main DB tables with the report DB and rewrite at TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use [SQL Server 2016 Data Masking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130841.aspx) as an alternative to your current scrubbing?